# Is it good design to store 500 mb of data in jvm cache which can be searched like a sql query?

Tags: performance, caching, lucene

I have a requirement to get results of search query within 1 second for a database table.The database table is returning results slowly at this point.A table has to be moved to a cache and searched from there so that search results come fast.I want to do google type page refresh on my existing search page -- which means the page should refresh as the user types.
In order to acheive this the search results should return within one second.My database is teradata.Its queries are taking 2 to 3 seconds at least.Hence i want to look for other options like caching.I want to use cache so that the resuls come fast.

Columns are
 **company  ,             Id    ,    Industry,        parent ...4 more**
Its a search page.So if user types "ja" all items starting from ja like

**company      -------------   Id       ------------- Industry  --------------parent**
jaico  ------------- 222 -------------paints ------------- Jaico asia
Jammy fruits------------- 232-------------food------------- jammy International

The table contains 3.2 million rows and there are 8 columns that are present.The search data need to return all 8 columns.Considering byte wise there are 150 chars per row.So total bytes are 3.2 million * 150 chars = 480 Megabytes .I need to store this much data in cache and then fire search queries like sql (grouping ,like ,order by) across them.What would be the best option to use in this case

1. ehcache
2. jboss cache
3. Inifinispan
4. Apache Lucene

Please suggest which option is good .Is it better to do caching in memory or to use lucene?
**What need to be cached?-->** It is a table of 3.2 million rows with 8 columns.
**Why it is to be cached?-->** It is to be cached so that search results come **faster** than sql query.If i use sql query it takes very long time.Hence i want to move towards caching data.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick, but I'm fairly sure that like .NET, Java uses 2 bytes per char, so that would double the memory use to at least 960 MB.

Comment: Well, it it's just for UX purposes, you can cheat pretty easily: have a small subset of the data always available to fill the first page of the results. By the time the user scans/reads the first page (I guess it will take more than 2-3 seconds), the main query should be finished.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Apache Solr - you can get that kind of performance with the right deployment. You can shard to distribute queries, for one thing.

Comment: solr will make text files from the database table and then store it on the local directory .it will return data from the local directory.Can u please explain the reason behind recommending apache solr above (ehcache or jbosscache or inifinispan):- (i)Will the SOLR work faster than the jboss cache OR(ii) The memory is too large to be handled by cache ? (iii) can the SOLR handle groupby queries ?

Comment: A second is a LOT of time for a Lucene query. For a simple prefix query like the one you mentioned you can expect response time on the order of 10 ms. Memory cache is a brute-force approach that scales poorly.

Comment: Solr uses Lucene of course. The benefit is that it has features to scan the database and create indexes, and features to distribute the search engine itself so you can maintain performance with any number of users. It also has features to do search suggestion out of the box you can use their javascript API for this. You also get customizable relevance ordering and lots of other features that you may find useful down the road.

Comment: I want a comparable statistics of (1.) ehcache
(2.)jboss cache
(3.)Inifinispan
(4)Apache Lucene .For the above scenario which one fits well and what are the advantage and disadvantages of the other API like jboss cache,infinispan,ehcache,ehcahe?Is there any link that shows the comparison of these.I want to arrive at a solution such that i have compared all the available methods analysed well .

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I wanted a comparable statistics of (1.) ehcache (2.)jboss cache (3.)Inifinispan (4)Apache Lucene .For the above scenario which one fits well and what are the advantage and disadvantages of the other API like jboss cache,infinispan,ehcache,ehcahe?Is there any link that shows the comparison of these.I want to arrive at a solution such that i have compared all the available methods analysed well .Reposting this as not getting response on the earlier post.

Comment: I don't have any links for you. Your original question did not specify you expected a comparison, just for people to suggest one from the list, and of course your comment is not nearly as visible to the community as the original question. Also, in the question you mention two entirely different requirements -- full-text search and general SQL-like capabilities. I don't advise a single solution for all such cases. Use Lucene for the full-text search and use SQL for what it is good at.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In such case could you suggest how to arrive at what suits requirement the best.i need to find out which of the 4 options     ehcache,
    jboss cache,
    Inifinispan,
    Apache Lucene
suits my requirement the best.

Comment: I don't think anyone following this question knows what your requirement really is, if it's not full-text searching, for which you already have your answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Improved the question.

Comment: I'd say your edit makes it that clearer that Solr/Lucene is the way to go. I know you already started using Lucene, so why do you keep inisting on this question?